# Iphone SDK - Count increments by 4 for each button tap

Tags: iphone

I have a simple routine to count everytime the user clicks a button.

However the integer (numberOfClicks) increments by four each time. Could the event be happening more than once for each user tap?

(btw the action method below is connected to the 'touch up inside' action)

```
- (IBAction)myButtonClicked
{
   numberOfClicks+=1;
   NSString *clicks = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number of clicks = %d", numberOfClicks];
   myLabel.text = clicks;
}
```

Many Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

If you add in a call like `NSLog(clicks)`, and you run the code, do you get the log message 4 times?

Are other buttons connected to this IBAction?

Have you connected this IBAction to more than one outlet of your single button -- i.e. Touch Up Inside, Touch Up Outside, Touch Drag Inside, Touch Drag Outside, etc.?

Comment: Hi there, I've check with the IB and it is only connected to the one button. The NSLog trace returns an increase of 4 each time, so still puzzled by this one.

Comment: From your code, `numberOfClicks` lives outside this function, maybe as a member variable. Is any other code modifying `numberOfClicks`? Where is it initialized?

Answer (score 0):

NSInteger is a primitive, not an object! What you are really doing is incrementing the address that the NSInteger* is pointing at. Since NSInteger is 4 bytes long, each time you increment it the compiler assumes that, since it's a pointer, you want to jump ahead to the next NSInteger in memory which is why you are getting multiples of 4. Just remove the '*' when you are declaring NSInteger and you should be all set. So, instead of declaring it like `int *NameOfDeclaration;` simply remove the `*` It would look like this `int NameOfDeclaration;`